# Enabling and disabling the sound of Firebase push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I want to add a toggle button to my application that can *enable* or *disable* the sound of Firebase push notifications of my app. Please tell me if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: have you searched ?

Comment: yes but i can not found result.